# What database is suited better to store a large number of small data

Tags: database

I need to store a lot (more than 100 000 records per minute) of a simple data, in style `id:time:value`.

Once an hour, I plan to collect this information to graph. What database suits better?

I think about nosql. But there are so much realisations, and I can not decide where to start. Or maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This data maps easily to a single relational table that is partitioned by hour (or that has the hour as the first column in the clustered index). It maps perfectly well onto the relational model.

Use NoSQL for this if you want to use multiple machines to scale the load. NoSQL style databases make that much easier.

For just 1666 records per second any old RDBMS is enough. Sequential bulk insert speeds vary from 10K to 200K rows per second per CPU core (4 cores => 800K rows per second) (please treat these numbers with a grain of salt).